# How to check if a variable is defined by name

Tags: php

I would like a function that only renders a variable if it is defined, otherwise do nothing. I don't want this check to happen (and error) in script mixed with html but rather in a function like so:

```
/**
* Echos a variable if it's set
*/
function render($var_name)
{
    if (eval('return(isset(' . $var_name . '))'))
        echo eval($var_name);
}
```

This errors with:

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting :: (T_PAAMAYIM_NEKUDOTAYIM) in inc\page.php(8) : eval()'d code on line 1 Call Stack #TimeMemoryFunctionLocation
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function render($var_name)
{
    if (isset($$var_name))
        echo $$var_name;
    else
        echo "not defined";
}
```

## [DEMO](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/w9r5-ejm9)

Answer (score 0):

```
     function render($value){
          if(isset($value)){
             echo $value;
        }
      }
```

Comment: This approach doesn't work because if you call `render($var)` where `$var` is undefined then an error will be thrown where the function was called.

Comment: always put some explanation to the answer you posted, so that others can get it easily.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to try something like this:

```
<?php
function render($var_name){
    if(isset($var_name)){
      return $var_name;
    }
    return false;
}

$test = 'TESTER';

echo render($test);
?>
```

Demo: https://eval.in/198437